# Cluster clickstream data

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, model-based-clustering

I've recently entered the realm of machine learning and a project I am working on requires me to cluster users based on the order they visited webpages on a website. I have data in the form of:

```
['user_id', 1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 7, 3, 2, 4...]
```

Where each number is a category/page that the user visited. In addition the length of data for each user is not the same i.e. some users visit more pages than others.

I realize this is really vague and defining similarity it hard. I tried following the example in this [research paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69752/tr-2000-18.pdf) and to be honest a lot of it went over my head.

I need help in how to approach this problem and am open to new ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

It is a good question with many practical applications.

Your data are sequential so we need a similarity measure between any pair of sequences. I recommend [Levensthein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) since it is very intuitive and very nicely defined. See also this nice [bachelor thesis](http://is.muni.cz/th/98936/fi_b/SimSearch_Metrics.pdf) with an overview of more measures for sequential data.

Finally, if one has the distances between all pairs of sequences, we can use any clustering algorithm that takes a distance matrix as input (for example any hierarchical algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

You can use package clickstream or clickclust in R language. It performs exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This is really better suited as a comment than an answer.